# Vienna, Austria: Recommendations for affordable overnight parking?

Tags: hotels, automobiles, austria, recommendations, vienna

I was searching for hotels in Vienna, Austria.

I found a good value Hotel but the hotel does not offer any overnight parking.

I tried to search over the internet for overnight parking but the websites for parking are not as robust as hotel websites.

**What are some good recommendations for good overnight parking in Vienna, Austria?**

My current idea is to drive to the Airport to park overnight. Then take transportation to Vienna from the Airport. But I'm not so sure of this idea.

Comment: Call/email the hotel and ask. They will either know some overnight public parking nearby, or have an agreement with some private venue (i.e. nearby hotel) to use their parking. And ask them how much it would cost, as it might turn the good-value-hotel into not-so-good.

Comment: Why would you want to park at the airport? It's expensive and not so close to the center. Maybe you could indicate how many days you're staying in Vienna and whether you want to use your car everyday. In short: In some districts further out (still more convenient than the airport), street parking is free, and there are also some pretty cheap parking garages.

Comment: Why would you want to use a car in an European city??

Comment: why does anyone get a car? why are there more than [300 million cars](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+many+cars+in+europe&oq=how+many+cars+in+europe&aqs=chrome..69i57.4855j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) in europe? answer: to travel. trip was: munich to vienna to halstatt to oberammergau to munich. rail/airplane didn't work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I searched the web for "Rick Steve parking in Vienna Austria"and came across [a recent 2018 forum thread that talks about parking in Vienna, Austria](https://community.ricksteves.com/travel-forum/austria/parking-in-vienna-dc00ecb2-46d3-43a2-8cab-04073a16dfad).

**The author writes about a "park and ride" car garage that operates 24 hours a day. The pricing is €3.4 to €5 per day or 5(as of this writing, 2018-03). And their locations are metro accessible.**

So the idea is to park in one of these franchisees parking lots on the outskirts of town and metro in to town. The total cost will be less compared to a Hotel or City car garage because are charging €15 to €20 compared to €3.4 to €5.

The author specifically calls out the Erdberg Park and Ride. I went to Google maps and found the business and clicked through to the website:

http://www.apcoa.at/en/parking-in/wien/p-r-erdberg.html

**Using the Erdberg Park and Ride let's you get affordable parking AND stay at a hotel that does not have parking (or charges unreasonable parking rates).**

---

Additional info:

The wien.info website lists other park and ride names. Or you can go to Google Maps and search for "park and ride":

- http://www.apcoa.at/en/parking-in/wien/p-r-erdberg.html
- http://www.bestinparking.at/garage/wien/spittelauer-laende/12 €17 per week
- €5 per day, € 18 per week http://www.apcoa.at/parken-in/wien/p-r-alfred-adler-strasse.html
- http://www.apcoa.at/parken-in/wien/p-r-ottakring.html
- http://www.bestinparking.at/de/garage/wien/deutschordenstrasse-3a

Comment: Yes, this is better than airport. Note that those garages are generally outside the city center, and some might be quite packed.

Comment: just an FYI I tried to check out spothero.com and as of this date/time spothero.com does not work in Austria (only US/Canada)

Answer (score 3):

Call/email the hotel and ask. They will either know some overnight public parking nearby, or have an agreement with some private venue (i.e. nearby hotel) to use their parking.

And ask them how much it would cost, as it might turn the good-value-hotel into not-so-good.

Comment: One of the hotels I found did not have parking offered (I did not call to inquire further). The other hotels were charging 15 to 20 €.

Answer (score 1):

A couple parking garages in the center of Vienna offer cheap overnight parking, usually starting at 18:00 or 20:00 where instead of paying something like 4€ per hour you pay a flat fee of maybe 8-12€ for the whole night, until a fixed time in the morning (8am or 9am?) when normal charging resumes. The details depend on the individual garage. In some of them you need a special ticket when you check out to make use of this.

Most of the parking garages have websites that explain their fees and special offers. Open Google Maps, search for parking garages near your hotel, then check their websites.

For hotel parking, the 15-20€ you mentioned in a comment is fairly standard within the city. At the edge or outside the city, many hotels offer free parking.

Note that you can also park your car on the street for free between 22:00 in the evening and 9:00 in the morning - see https://www.wien.gv.at/verkehr/parken/